# How to monitor health condition of a elastic search server from our java application written in spring boot ? latest version any idea / references?

Tags: elasticsearch, server, backend

I have given a task where I have to monitor the health condition(status of a elastic search server whether it is Green/Red/Yellow) from a java spring boot application ( using java ElasticSearch asynchronous client from my original application)
I have to connect to the server using this application client and then find the condition of elastic search server.

I am new to elastic search

Answer (score 0):

It Is possible to execute a GET Http request which returns the following response

```
GET host:port/_cluster/health

{
  "cluster_name" : "testcluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1,
  "active_shards" : 1,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 50.0
}
```

In order to execute http requests with Java, you can use the [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/) like this:

```
GetMethod get = new GetMethod("url");
InputStream in = get.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// Process the response and parse the status.
get.releaseConnection();
```

You can use a java library to parse the json response and access the field **status**

to parse the json you can one the following libraries :

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/)

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

[org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

It Is also possible to use the [Elasticsearch Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/getting-started-java.html) and get the result directly like this (this Is what I'll do):

```
ClusterHealthResponse response = client.cluster().health(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
ClusterHealthStatus status = response.getStatus();
```

check the official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-cluster-health.html)

Hope this helps, good luck